# Passing GPS coordinates to Phone

Tags: java, android, gps, ddms

I wanted to know whether there's a way to pass on GPS coordinates to a real device.

For example - when I use an emulator , I pass on GPS coordinates to the emulator using DDMS on Eclipse - however , DDMS doesn't seem to work when i want to transfer coordinates to a **phone** . I'd like to do this since my GPS antenna doesn't seem to catch any signals , since I'm working in a closed space, and its necessary to emulate my app on my phone

Hence , I'd like to know whether or not I can pass GPS coordinates to my phone through my PC

I'd really appreciate any replies

Thanks

Comment: Did you allow Mock locations on the phone? 

`Settings>Applications>Development>Allow mock locations`

You should be able to send coords from ddms, just select phone from devices...

Comment: @vtuhtan yes i have. But the GPS options in DDMS still seem to be disabled

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An App called Location Spoofer does the Job